# Is there anyway to set a variable equal to function that is called everytime the variable is accessed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-create the 'useState' hook from React as a silly fun personal exercise, but am encountering trouble when accessing variables from my 'global state'. I know that this has no practical use outside of react, but I just thought it would be something to attempt regardless.

Currently I have the following implementation below, but because the destructured variable is set only that first time and is not updated when using the corresponding setter, it always will return the same variable. I fully understand why this is happening but I am unsure if there is a way to get this working at all or if this is a lost cause. The destructured setter does update the global state, but the variable is of course as previously mentioned not accessing the global state again since it is only set that initial time.

```
let PROP_ID = 0;
let GLOBAL_STATE = {};

const useState = prop => {
  const id = PROP_ID++;
  GLOBAL_STATE[id] = prop;

  return [
    (() => {
      return GLOBAL_STATE[id];
    })(),
    function(nv) {
      GLOBAL_STATE[id] = nv;
    }
  ];
};

const [userName, setUserName] = useState("Chris");
const [favCol, setFavCol] = useState("red");

console.log(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log(userName);

setUserName("Bob");

console.dir(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log(userName);
```

All I want to know if there is a way to set the destructured reference variable equal to some sort of function that will always be called to get the new variable from the global state when that variable is referenced.

Comment: (Responding to deleted question.) Rather than deleting, answer it, or close it as a typo, or whatever--I was in the middle of a conversation in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a piece of the puzzle here.

React hooks depend on the position of their call *within a given functional component*. Without the encapsulating function, you remove the usefulness of the state being provided by the hook, because they're only being called once in your example, thus the reference in the destructuring syntax never gets updated as you observed.

Let's get them working in the context of functions.

```js
const { component, useState } = (function () {
  const functions = new WeakMap()
  const stack = []
  let hooks
  let index

  function component (fn) {
    return function (...args) {
      try {
        stack.push({ hooks, index })
        hooks = functions.get(fn)
        index = 0

        if (!hooks) {
          functions.set(fn, hooks = [])
        }

        return fn.apply(this, args)
      } finally {
        ({ hooks, index } = stack.pop())
      }
    }
  }

  function useState (initialValue) {
    const hook = index++

    if (hook === hooks.length) {
      hooks.push(initialValue)
    }

    return [
      hooks[hook],
      function setState (action) {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
          hooks[hook] = action(hooks[hook])
        } else {
          hooks[hook] = action
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  return { component, useState }
})()

const fibonacci = component(function () {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1)
  const [b, setB] = useState(1)

  setA(b)
  setB(a + b)

  return a
})

const sequence = component(function () {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  setText(
    text.length === 0
    ? fibonacci().toString()
    : [text, fibonacci()].join()
  )

  return text
})

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  console.log(sequence())
}
```

The `stack` variable here allows us to nest our stateful function calls, and the `hooks` variable keeps track of the existing hook states by position within the currently executing `component` of the `stack`.

This implementation might seem overly-complicated, but the point of `component()` and `stack` is to partially mimic how the React framework treats functional components. This is still much simpler than how React works, because we're treating all calls of the same function as if it's the same instance of a functional component.

On the other hand, in React, a particular function could be used for several different instances, distinguishable from each other based on a number of factors such as the position in the hierarchy of the virtual DOM, the `key` and `ref` props, etc., so it's much more complicated than this.

---

It occurs to me you just want to get *your* example working. For that, all you need to do is change your variable to a getter function:

```js
const useState = state => [
  () => state,
  value => { state = value }
];

const [getUserName, setUserName] = useState('Chris');
const [getFavCol, setFavCol] = useState('red');

console.log(getUserName());
setUserName('Bob');
console.log(getUserName());
```

Much simpler than what you had and doesn't require any globals to work.

If the manual getter seems too inconvenient, then you can't destructure, but you can implement an approach that's almost as easy to use:

```js
const useState = state => ({
  get state () { return state },
  set (value) { state = value }
});

const userName = useState('Chris');
const favCol = useState('red');

console.log(userName.state);
userName.set('Bob');
console.log(userName.state);
```

Comment: I had implemented your first answer at one point and was pretty happy with it, but again I had posed this question to see if it was possible without a getter function. I like your second solution as well, very smart. Thank you for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question.

The short answer is: **no, that’s not possible***.

### The long answer

The long answer is how JavaScript handles primitives and objects. Primitives values are copied during assignment (`userName` here: `const [userName, setUserName] = useState("Chris");` which is a string), while in case of object a reference would be copied.

In order to play with it, I came with something like that (*mind you, that is not solution to your challenge, rather explanation to my answer*):

```
let PROP_ID = 0;
let GLOBAL_STATE = {};

const useState = prop => {
  const id = PROP_ID++;
  GLOBAL_STATE[id] = {
      _value: prop,
      [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { return this._value },
  }

  const tuple = [
    GLOBAL_STATE[id],
    (nv) => GLOBAL_STATE[id]._value = nv,
  ];

  return tuple;
};

const [userName, setUserName] = useState("Chris");
const [favCol, setFavCol] = useState("red");

console.log(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log(userName);

console.log('set user name to:', setUserName("Bob"));

console.dir(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log('' + userName);
```

`GLOBAL_STATE` entry is now object, so when you destructure it after calling `useState` only a reference is changed. Then update changes data inside this object but what we assigned in the first place is still there.

I added `Symbo.toPrimitive` property which coerses object to a primitive value but sadly, this will not work on it’s own. Only when run as `'' + userName`. Which means it behaves differently than you expected. At this point I stopped experimenting.

### React

I went to Facebook’s Github and tried to trace what they are doing but gave up due to imports of imports of imports. Hence, I will take an educated guess here, based on Hooks API behaviour. I think that your implementation is rather faithful to the original. We use `useState` in a function and the value doesn’t change there. Only when state is changed and then the component is re-rendered with a new value, which again is assigned and won’t change.

---

*I will gladly welcome anyone who proves this notion wrong.

Comment: Interesting take.  Why is it that when userName is only mixed in with an operation that it fetches the latest value?

Comment: Answering my own comment after some quick research... Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive, the act of `''+userName` is coercing the need to convert userName to a primitive, in this case a string.

Comment: It's possible :) See the bottom of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023661/1541563). Not sure if you'd consider it cheating though

Comment: Function seems like natural solution but it’s still not what author of question was asking for: is it possible to have a value that is actually a concealed function call every time someone reads from it (which is more or less a definition of getter in JS but it has to be on a object). But let’s not be too harsh to each other. This was theoretical and experimental question from the beginning.

Comment: Hear hear!  The combination of destructuring and the need for a getter is the crux of the challenge.  Roberts' last two clear code samples show the use of one or the other but not both simultaneously, not due to any lack of skill...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had no idea that you could do something like this. Its somewhat hacky, but I think that it is a neat answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the following lines...

```
let PROP_ID = 0;
let GLOBAL_STATE = {};

const useState = (varName, prop) => {
  const id = PROP_ID++;
  GLOBAL_STATE[id] = prop;

  Object.defineProperty(window, varName, {
    get: function(){
      return GLOBAL_STATE[id];
    }
  });

  return ((nv) => {
      GLOBAL_STATE[id] = nv;
    });
};

const setUserName = useState("userName", "Chris");
const setFavCol = useState("favCol", "red");

console.log(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log(userName);

setUserName("Bob");

console.dir(GLOBAL_STATE);
console.log(userName);
```

Note that I've changed your interface a bit such that you have to pass the name of the variable to the `useState` function.  Seems a bit kludgey, but allows a getter to be configured, in this case, following your example, on the global scope (ie, "window"), which might not be the best practice.

Comment: This is extending `window` object which is a shared state for everyone, hence: a) this is not safe, as anyone can reach there and change it, and b) this will stay there as long as page is loaded which can lead to memory leaks. Now, a) could be addressesd with `Symbol()` but I still think that’s not the best idea.

Comment: To be fair, I think there is no good idea here but I will address it in my answer. This was a good try, anyway.

Comment: @Witness, by "not safe", I presume you simply mean that as part of the global scope, an object is at risk of collision with other imports, etc.  But having an object residing in the global scope is not in itself going to lead to memory leaks.

Comment: The scenario I had in mind was some more elaborate objects that are not deleted once they are not needed (as `window` is always there and so are its references). In the long run it would get more and more cluttered.

Comment: I appreciate your solution. I was thinking something along the lines of this but I am please to have learned something knew about the side-effects of this that @TheWitness mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but only if you're okay using a dirty, dirty hack.

The following approach uses a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement and a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) containing a custom [`get` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get), and requires object destructuring syntax in order to determine the variable name from the property key of the setter function:

```js
// initialize useState() hook with independent scope
function createHook (scope = Object.create(null)) {
  const setter = /^set([A-Z][^\W_]*)$/;

  function useState (initialValue) {
    // return proxy from useState() so that object destructuring syntax
    // can be used to get variable name and initialize setter function
    return new Proxy(scope, {
      get (target, propertyKey) {
        if (!setter.test(propertyKey)) {
          throw new TypeError(`Invalid setter name '${propertyKey}'`);
        }

        // get variable name from property key of setter function
        const [, name] = propertyKey.match(setter);
        const key = name[0].toLowerCase() + name.slice(1);

        // support updater callback
        const setState = value => {
          target[key] = (
            typeof value === 'function'
            ? value(target[key])
            : value
          );
        };

        // initialize state
        setState(initialValue);

        // return setter as property value
        return setState;
      }
    });
  }

  return { scope, useState };
}

// example usage with a little magic
{
  const { scope, useState } = createHook();
  const { setFoo } = useState('bar');

  console.log(scope.foo);

  setFoo(42);

  console.log(scope.foo);
}

// example use with more magic
const { scope, useState } = createHook();

with (scope) {
  const { setUserName } = useState('Chris');
  const { setFavCol } = useState('red');

  console.log(userName, favCol);

  setUserName('Bob');
  setFavCol(color => `dark${color}`);

  console.log(userName, favCol);
}
```

The following usage ends up being very similar to [Jon Trent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023256/1541563) by abusing implicit globals:

```js
function createHook(e=Object.create(null)){var t=/^set([A-Z][^\W_]*)$/;return{scope:e,useState:n=>new Proxy(e,{get(e,r){if(!t.test(r))throw new TypeError(`Invalid setter name '${r}'`);var[,o]=r.match(t),c=o[0].toLowerCase()+o.slice(1),s=t=>{e[c]="function"==typeof t?t(e[c]):t};return s(n),s}})}}

const { useState } = createHook(window);
const { setUserName } = useState('Chris');
const { setFavCol } = useState('red');

console.log(userName, favCol);

setUserName('Bob');
setFavCol(color => `dark${color}`);

console.log(userName, favCol);
```