# Why doesn't useState function initialize state every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function HookCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HookCounter;
```

React calls this function every time when it needs to re-render.

But why doesn't it initialize the state every time?

When exit the function, life of variables is ended, isn't it?

But how does it keep saving values of states?

I don't understand.

In `useState` function, is there any logic for that?

Comment: Hooks aren't vanilla functions, they're magical. useState stores values internally in react's core, and passes updated, not initial, values back to your component when the render function is executed again

Comment: The initialization is done just once. It runs on every render, but the result is disregarded. You can also pass a function to initialize the state, this one runs just once. `const[s,setter] = useState(() => 3)`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: Outside the function? I don't see using count in another component. It's only available in that component unless you pass them.

Comment: @AndyRay not magical, but they're definitely not pure. The implementation relies on relative ordering of hook calls within a component in order to propagate state between passes.

Comment: Yes, magical, not just unpure. You can't nest them, order matters, you can't call them in certain places, that's why you have to prefix the name with "use" so linters can find them and enforce certain rules.

Comment: @AndyRay you can certainly nest them... otherwise custom hooks would not be possible. All that matters is that the relative ordering of calls within a component to the React-provided hooks remains the same for all renders. Here's a very simplified [pseudo-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023661/1541563) of how hooks work under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

`useState` as a function is storing the value you gave it within React's core. When the component re-renders, React is going to pass the updated count from its core to the component.

More information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 2):

State is initialized only once when you create the component, this is how `React` works. From the documentation:

> What does calling useState do? It declares a “state variable”. Normally, variables “disappear” when the function exits but state variables are preserved by React.

Just to have the context here, let me summarize what is `useState` and how it works in more details.

**What is `useState`:**

So `useState` is a hook which helps you to handle state in a functional component.

**How is it working?**

Once you call `useState` you need to pass the initial value of the state what you would like to use in your functional component. It returns a pair of values the `count` and `setCount`.

So let's have your example below:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

So `useState` returned two items where `count` is the current value. And the second item, `setCount` is a function which can be used to update the value of the `count` state.

`count` can be used to represent the state for example the value in a `div` element:

```
return (
   <div>{count}</div>
)
```

In order to update the value you can achieve by calling `setState(12)`.

From the docs you can read further [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to the React official website:

React keeps track of the currently rendering component. Thanks to the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), we know that Hooks are only called from React components (or custom Hooks — which are also only called from React components).

There is an internal list of **“memory cells”** associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like `useState()`, it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple `useState()` calls each get independent local state.

Reference:

[How does React associate Hook calls with components?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components)

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't useState function initialize State every time?

I think you're confused with:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

As it's just a variable!?!

Yes, it's just a variable but it will take everytime the function runs from the useState hook. And it is the local state like you have seen in class based component.